# Removing embedded crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, resources

I've inherited a VB.NET application, where there's a series of Crystal Report RPT files that get embedded into the application at compile time.  It appears that there are also som VB classes that encapsulate these reports, and are accessed this way.

The requirement I received was they do not want these RPT files embedded anymore, they wish to leave them as external files so the end user can modify them if they so desire.

What do I need to do to keep these RPT files as external files, and then what (if anything) do I have to do with these wrapper classes?  It looks as if these classes were auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar and have never had trouble with the wrapper classes.  The RPT files are what truly matter.

Open your solution in visual studio, go to the properties of the RPT file and set `Build Action` to `Content`.

Comment: Thank you, I've never used the Content in the Build Action.  If I may, this will still put the RPT files into the runtime directory (where the EXE resides) right?  What if I ant the actual reports (when installed) to be in a different directory?

Comment: BTW, I did this and it copied the files to a Reports directory in my BIN directory, and it also copied the associated VB class files into the same directory.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Not sure.  My crystal reports reside in a /Reports/ folder at the same level as my /bin/ folder (not under) when both in VS and when installed.  My solution is a Web Application.  The build action for the report's .vb files should be compile.

Comment: The classes do not physically exist until the time of compilation.  Each report has CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator entered for the Custom Tool in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of VB.NET project (Class Library). My DLL was getting bigger with each Crystal added, 12 Mb. I ended up in setting `Build Action` to `None` in each RPT and deleting each .vb wrapper classes. My finaly DLL file is now 64 KB !